# Set environment variable in env file based on other environment variable in docker

Tags: docker

I have the base image of `go`. This image has as default variable `$GOPATH=/go`
Now I want to start a container from this image like this:

```
$ docker run -env-file ./myenvfile go
```

The content of myenvfile is

```
TEST=$GOPATH/other/path
```

When I start my container and I do an `echo $TEST` the output is `$GOPATH/other/path` while I was hoping for `/go/other/path`.

Is it possible to reuse existing environment variables in you env-file of docker?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible since Docker does not apply substitution on those variables. However, you can do this manually in the container. YMMV, I did my testing with command line arguments.

```
$ docker run -it --rm -e TEST1="my-path" -e TEST2='$TEST1/test' ubuntu bash
root@050cb6f12749:/# echo "$TEST1"
my-path
root@050cb6f12749:/# echo "$TEST2"
$TEST1/test
```

`$TEST1` is in the output since bash interprets what you write in the command line but not what is in the variable. Thus, adding `eval` resolves `$TEST`:

```
root@050cb6f12749:/# eval echo "$TEST2"
my-path/test
```

`echo` and `"$TEST2"` are arguments for `eval` here. But before `eval` is executed `$TEST2` is replaced with `$TEST1/test` by bash. Thus, `echo` and `$TEST1/test` is given to `eval` which interprets `$TEST1` and replaces it with `my-path`.

Using `eval`, however, poses some security risks, but it works out of the box. There is an alternative, `envsubst`, for which you first have to install:

```
root@050cb6f12749:/# apt update && apt install -y gettext-base
[...]
root@050cb6f12749:/# echo "$TEST2" | envsubst
my-path/test
```

As `envsubst` can not be hijacked to execute arbitrary commands its more secure.

You could use the former techniques in a `ENTRYPOINT` script to expand the environment variables in a transparent manner, e.g. (not tested)

```
#!/bin/bash

export TEST2=`echo $TEST2 | envsubst`

exec "$@"
```